# how do I solve the missing modules problem in parse server

Tags: node.js, express, parse-platform

I have installed the parse server and it runs the single command post/put correctly.

However, after I added the express.js framework, I used “npm start – /var/www/parse_server/config.json” to run the server.

Then, I got the following errors.

How do I install the missing modules? Thanks

```
(1to1call) Tom:parse_server mariolzx$ npm start -- /var/www/parse_server/config.json

> parse-server@4.5.0 start /private/var/www/parse_server/parse_server
> node ./bin/parse-server "/var/www/parse_server/config.json"

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:969
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/var/www/parse_server/config.json'
Require stack:
- /private/var/www/parse_server/parse_server/lib/cli/utils/commander.js
- /private/var/www/parse_server/parse_server/lib/cli/utils/runner.js
- /private/var/www/parse_server/parse_server/lib/cli/parse-server.js
- /private/var/www/parse_server/parse_server/bin/parse-server
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:966:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:842:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at parseConfigFile (/private/var/www/parse_server/parse_server/lib/cli/utils/commander.js:93:24)
    at Command._commander.Command.parse (/private/var/www/parse_server/parse_server/lib/cli/utils/commander.js:139:20)
    at _default (/private/var/www/parse_server/parse_server/lib/cli/utils/runner.js:57:22)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/private/var/www/parse_server/parse_server/lib/cli/parse-server.js:38:21)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/private/var/www/parse_server/parse_server/lib/cli/utils/commander.js',
    '/private/var/www/parse_server/parse_server/lib/cli/utils/runner.js',
    '/private/var/www/parse_server/parse_server/lib/cli/parse-server.js',
    '/private/var/www/parse_server/parse_server/bin/parse-server'
  ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! parse-server@4.5.0 start: `node ./bin/parse-server "/var/www/parse_server/config.json"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the parse-server@4.5.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/mariolzx/.npm/_logs/2021-02-28T01_57_37_051Z-debug.log
(1to1call) Tom:parse_server mariolzx$ npm start -- /var/www/parse_server/config.json
```

Comment: Have you created this missing file in your server? It should be your parse server configuration file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried to use inline parameters. It works. However, when I supply the parameters in config.json, it does not work. Yes, config.json is there. I also tried "npm start – config.json" and it does not work either. But I think it is fine if the config.json file does not work. I can always use inline parameter.

Comment: Try with `./bin/parse-server /var/www/parse_server/config.json`